# Is double-braced scalar initialization allowed by the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I have the following code:

```
int x = {{}};
```

Is this syntax valid according to the C++ standard? (I'm interested in C++11 and later.)

When using the latest compilers there is no problem, however in some older ones (e.g. GCC 4.8.5) it gives following error:

> error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'int'

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is ill-formed. gcc is wrong to accept it and clang seems to allow it as an extension, as [it warns about it](https://godbolt.org/z/1Xa35k).

I'm going to quote the latest draft, but it doesn't make a difference. List initialization works as follows as per [[dcl.init.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3), where T is `int` in this case:

- If the initializer list is a *designated initializer list*, [...] => it's not
- If T is an aggregate class [...] => it's not
- If T is a character array [...] => it's not.
- If T is an aggregate [...] => it's not (only arrays and classes can be aggregates)
- If the initializer list has no elements [...] => it doesn't
- If T is a specialization of std::initializer_list [...] => it's not
- If T is a class type [...] => it's not
- If T is an enumeration with fixed underlying type [...] => it's not
- If the initializer list has a single element of type E [...] => a braced initializer list has no type, so no
- If T is a reference type [...] => it isn't
- If the initializer list has no elements [...] => it doesn't
- Otherwise the program is ill-formed

Comment: +1 and see also [core language issue 1501](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1501) which follows the same logic as this answer to explicitly say that it's invalid.